# Andorid - Abrir Activity apenas uma vez

Tags: java, android

Como faço para que uma Activity abra apenas na primeira vez que o app for inicializado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, conceitualmente a **primeira vez de uso** de um aplicativo, se o controle for offline, é feito diretamente pelo próprio aplicativo, ou seja, você mesmo precisa fazer este controle.

Você pode fazer isto de diversas maneiras. A mais simples é utilizar Preferências Compartilhadas.

Por exemplo, antes da possível inicialização da Activity você pode checar a existência de um determinado valor. Veja:

```
//obter SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
//chave de checagem
String isnew = prefs.getString("primeira_vez", null);
if (isnew != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "Não é a primeira vez");
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
} else {
  //... inicialize a atividade
  //... altera o valor de "primeira_vez" para "usado"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar na `Main`, um flag em `SharedPreferences`, e verificá-lo toda vez que o app iniciar. Caso o flag tiver `false`, abre a `activity` desejada e já altera para `true`.

Não achei aqui um projeto que havia feito, mas achei um [AQUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006796/one-time-splash-screen).

Exemplo:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    boolean splash;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        splash = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("Splash", false);
        if (splash == true) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            //animation
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Animation alpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.fade_in);

            imageView.startAnimation(alpha);

            alpha.setAnimationListener((new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Start your activity here.
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("Splash", true);
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    Splash.this.finish();
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```